# Okhttp3+android, запрос в главном потоке (синхронный)

Tags: android, okhttp

Собственно известная ошибка

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Очень нужно сделать синхронный запрос с помощью `okhttp3`. Асинхронный с Callback'ом совсем плохо на логику ложится.

Есть опыт, как такое лучше всего организовывать?

Comment: google запретили делать http запросы в главном потоке. Для подобных запросов лучше использовать сервисы

Comment: Такое категорически нельзя делать. Ваше приложение, в случае задержки, просто скажет, что приложение зависло (и оно действительно зависнет, ведь UI не будет отвечать). Пересмотрите архитектуру, а еще лучше, если не знакомы, познакомьтесь с Retrofit и RxJava, они очень упрощают работу с асинхронными запросами (и никаких каллебков).